# Why twisted is not installed on CentOS, Python version is 2.7 and pip is using same python command

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, twisted

```
sudo pip install twisted
```

> Collecting twisted

Using cached Twisted-15.5.0.tar.bz2

```
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 20, in <module>
  File "/tmp/pip-build-WTSzv5/twisted/setup.py", line 64, in <module>
    main(sys.argv[1:])
  File "/tmp/pip-build-WTSzv5/twisted/setup.py", line 45, in main
    from twisted.python.dist import (
  File "./twisted/__init__.py", line 55, in <module>
    _checkRequirements()
  File "./twisted/__init__.py", line 17, in _checkRequirements
    raise ImportError("Twisted requires Python 2.7 or later.")
ImportError: Twisted requires Python 2.7 or later.


----------------------------------------
```

Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-WTSzv5/twisted

```
pip --version
```

pip 7.1.2 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-7.1.2-py2.7.egg (python 2.7)

Comment: What is the output of `sudo pip --version`?

Comment: pip 7.1.2 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-7.1.2-py2.7.egg (python 2.7)

Answer (score 2):

Solution must be simple.

> > ImportError: Twisted requires Python 2.7 or later.

Just update your python up to 2.7+

Answer (score 0):

If you are running Centos 6 for example it is not simple at all since there is no newer version in any repository to update to.  It requires you to manually download and compile Python and all related utils that you need including pip.

Also note that you cannot easily replace your 2.6 version in Centos or things including yum break.  If you install along side of your 2.6 then it is easier but you'll have to manually run python2.7 and pip2.7 to use the new version.  It is the only solution I've found.